# looking for jquery solution to map_canvas issue in Google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Apparently a Google map is only displayed in a div if it is called 'map_canvas', which is causing me a bit of a problem. Without going into too much detail, my app is Rails based, with different pages being rendered, and on one page I want to call initialize_google_maps() and on the other page I want to call initialize_google_maps2()

But how can I distinguish between the two different pages? Any ideas? For example I was using the code below, and in the page with map_canvas2 I thought I was being smart by having map_canvas nested, like:

```
<div id="map_canvas2">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

But when I do that both functions are called - initialize_google_maps(); and initialize_google_maps2(); The code I have is:

```
        if ($("#map_canvas").length)
        {

            initialize_google_maps();
        }

    if ($("#map_canvas2").length)
    {

      initialize_google_maps2();
    }
```

Any ideas how to distinguish between them? Thanks.

And my initialize function goes something like (getElementById MUST be called 'map_canvas', from what I've read):

```
function initialize_google_maps() {

    console.log('map canvas again'); 
    var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(map_latitude, map_longitude);
    var zoom = 10;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: currentlatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID
        streetViewControl: false
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    console.log("definition of map"); 

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: currentlatlng, icon:{oppacity:0}});
   // map.setCenter(currentlatlng);
   // map.setZoom(zoom);
     console.log("definition of marker"); 

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeOpacity: 0.7,
        radius: 10000,
    });
    console.log("definition of circle"); 
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
console.log("circle2");
  }
```

Comment: `Apparently a Google map is only displayed in a div if it is called 'map_canvas'` - that is not true.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the line below it says ("map_canvas") you can change that to whatever name you need. Just make sure in your div it matches what you changed that to in that line.

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    console.log("definition of map");
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

`if ($("#map_canvas").length > 0)`